# installing dotnet6 on ubuntu 22.04 WSL2 - installed but not showing in sdk-list

Tags: software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dotnet

I am slowly transitioning to use ubuntu / linux WSL2 as primary for development - instead of windows, but there are still a lot of things I don't understand and have to look up, I am guessing this is one of those things

Have clean installed dotnet6 by using

```
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet6
```

Install is successful, however after running list sdks I get the following

```
dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.421 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.408 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

also noticed that dotnet6 is not actually installed in the location `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk` where the other sdks are installed by default,
instead it is installed in `/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/sdk/6.0.108` when I used the above mentioned apt-get

How do I get `dotnet` tool to pick up that dotnet6 is installed ?

I am using oh-myzsh

Comment: I am having exact same problem on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: How did you install the other SDKs?  Homebrew?  `dotnet-install.sh`?  Another method?

Comment: I installed using apt-get 

sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet6

Comment: Right, you cover that in your question.   But again, how did you install the *other* SDKs - 3.1.421 and 5.0.408.  Those aren't installed when you do `sudo apt-get install -y dotnet6`, right?  Or are you thinking they were?

Comment: Hmm.. that could be it - I don't remember how I installed the others as they were installed a while ago (I think I did add a repo ) , and yes I did had to update WSL from 20.04 to 22.04 - let me remove those (5 is not needed) and then check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got dotnet6 to work,

I discovered that previously I had installed dotnet 3.1 and dotnet 5 using the script method on WSL 20.04 - [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install), then upgraded to WSL 22.04 and installed dotnet6 using `apt-get` after which the `dotnet --list-sdks` would not pick up dotnet6

so here's the problem - dotnet3.1 / dotnet5 does not support SSL3 and therefore will actually not work  / not available as a package install on WSL 22.04

[read this comment here on the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7038#issuecomment-1110377345)

So I had to manually uninstall dotnet6 and other dotnet versions refer to:

[remove script installed dotnet manually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-linux#uninstall-net)

dotnet6 was removed using `sudo apt remove dotnet6` then running `sudo apt autoremove` to remove any remaining depenednecies

I just removed my dotnet folder under `/usr/shared/` and re-installed dotnet 6 using `sudo apt-get install -y dotnet6`, of course it means I can't really use dotnet 3.1 under WSL 22.04 but at least my `dotnet` command is recognized and I can use `dotnet --lisk-sdks` and it picks up dotnet6 correctly

Hope anyone else stumbling into this problem finds this useful